# How to stop repeating a background image in html email without using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I made a picture to use as a background. I tried using that picture with CSS but Outlook doesn't support that. So I just put the picture in body tag. Now I am able to display the picture but it is repeating.

I tried to stop repeating using CSS background repeat: no-repeat; but it isn't working. Whenever I try to use CSS on that background image, the image is not at all displaying in my email.

So I need a way to stop repetition of background image in HTML without using CSS.

Any help?

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1):

Email clients are notoriously bad at interpreting CSS or any standards for that matter. You can take a peek at this list: http://www.email-standards.org/clients/ to see what is and what isn't supported by the client you're targetting.

Keep in mind however that using images or extensive markup in e-mail messages will most likely (read: always) lead to headaches and - if possible - need to be avoided.

Comment: also adding this resource for email client css handling: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/